# Is it permissible to have sexual relation with someone not married to you, such as someone your right hand possesses?

Tags: halal-haram, sex, slavery

Is it permitted in Islam to have sexual relation with someone who is consent and willing yet not being in marriage bond?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. To make yourself familiar with our site and model I strongly suggest you to take our [tour] and check our [help]. Why should something (adultery) which is clearly haram be halal only due to consent or whatever? You can't make a free person your slave even more and especially not if he/she will be a slave for special purposes.

Comment: These posts seem relevant: [Are Muslim men allowed to take sex slaves](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/649/are-muslim-men-allowed-to-take-sex-slaves), [Can I take a non-Muslim free girl as my slave and have sex with her?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25834/can-i-take-a-non-muslimfree-girl-as-my-slave-and-have-sex-with-her?) and [What us the meaning of what your right hand possess?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/26147/what-is-the-meaning-of-those-your-right-hands-possess-in-424)

Answer (score 4):

**ملكت** أيمانكم (***Malakat** aymanukum*) means those who you **own**, i.e. slaves. Refer to [4:25](https://quran.com/4/25), [24:32](https://quran.com/24/33), [30:28](https://quran.com/30/28), [16:17](https://quran.com/16/71), [16:75](https://quran.com/16/75) etc.

It is permissible for a Muslim man to have sexual relations with a slave woman that he personally owns, without requiring a marriage contract (Nikah) since the exclusive ownership and authority substitutes for that.

> And they who guard their private parts. Except from their wives or those their right hands possess, for indeed, they will not be blamed.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 23:5-6](https://quran.com/23/5-7)</sup>

If a child is born to the slave from her owner, then she becomes an *Ummal Walad* (mother of the son) and can never be sold and is automatically freed on the owner's death.

Similar to marriage, no two men can simultaneously keep relations with a slave woman. It is not permissible to have sexual relations with a slave that someone else owns, unless you formally marry them; and if someone marries them then it is not permissible for the owner to have relations with them.

---

Regarding your question:

```
Is it permitted in Islam to have sexual relation with someone 
who is consent and willing yet not being in marriage bond
```

The answer is **No**. Such a person will neither be your spouse nor your legal slave, but what you desire is something beyond that and hence verse 7 of Surah Al-Muminun applies:

> But whoever seeks beyond that, then those are the transgressors
>
> <sup>— [Quran 23:7](https://quran.com/23/5-7)</sup>

It would be Zina (fornication\adultery) and will not protect the rights of the partners nor the rights and lineage of any potential children.

Comment: The Coranic verses always say *maa malakat aymanukum* (what your right hand possesses), not *man malakat aymanukum* (whom your right hand posesses), so it's not talking about people (*man*), but objects (*maa*).

Comment: @CarlMasens Not sure what you are implying. **maa** and **man**  are at times used interchangeably. *maa* is used for people in the meaning of whom, for example it is used for women in [4:3](http://quran.com/4/3)  ما طاب لكم i.e. whom you like. For humans in [90:3](http://quran.com/90/3) ووالد وما ولد i.e. whom he begot. For Allah in [91:5](http://quran.com/91/5-7) والسماء وما بناها i.e. whom built it. There are also other examples.